# Can't send a keyedMessage to brokers with partitioner.class=kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 2 nodes kafka cluster with 2 instances of brokers and zookeepers. And then I create a topic kafka-test with 2 partitions and replication-factor =2. My producer config is:
                      {"partitioner.class" "kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner"
                      "metadata.broker.list" "172.32.1.248:9092,172.32.1.251:9092"
                      "request.required.acks" "1"}

So for the DefaultPartitoner, it will calculate and hashvalue and divide by the num_partiton to decide which partition the data it will go, so I create my keyedMessage
val key-msg = KeyedMessage("kafka-test","a","test message!")
prod.send(key-msg)

"a"'s hashValue is 97 and 97 % 2 = 1, so the data should go to partition1. However, the data did't get send to the brokers (I have a console consumer running that didn't receive any message from this topic). If I create the key-msg without the key, it works fine

val key-msg = KeyedMessage("kafka-test","test message!")
prod.send(key-msg)

Am I using the key wrong or anything?
Thanks

Comment: does this mean the value was not even produced to the queue or you didn't receive that under expected partition?

Comment: The value was not able to produced to the queue.