# kafka-python 1.3.3: KafkaProducer.send with explicit key fails to send message to broker

Tags: kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

(*Possibly* a duplicate of [Can't send a keyedMessage to brokers with partitioner.class=kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28412028/1337498), although the OP of that question didn't mention kafka-python. And anyway, it never got an answer.)

I have a Python program that has been successfully (for many months) sending messages to the Kafka broker, using essentially the following logic:

```
producer = kafka.KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[some_addr],
                               retries=3)
...
msg = json.dumps(some_message)
res = producer.send(some_topic, value=msg)
```

Recently, I tried to upgrade it to send messages to different partitions based on a definite key value extracted from the message:

```
producer = kafka.KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[some_addr],
                               key_serializer=str.encode,
                               retries=3)
...
try: 
    key = some_message[0]
except:
    key = None
msg = json.dumps(some_message)
res = producer.send(some_topic, value=msg, key=key)
```

However, with this code, *no* messages ever make it out of the program to the broker. I've verified that the key value extracted from `some_message` is always a valid string. Presumably I don't need to define my own `partitioner`, since, according to the documentation:

> The default partitioner implementation hashes each non-None key using the same murmur2 algorithm as the java client so that messages with the same key are assigned to the same partition.

Furthermore, with the new code, when I try to determine what happened to my `send` by calling `res.get` (to obtain a `kafka.FutureRecordMetadata`), *that* call throws a `TypeError` exception with the message `descriptor 'encode' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'`.

(As a side question, I'm not exactly sure what I'd do with the `FutureRecordMetadata` if I were actually able to get it. Based on the kafka-python source code, I assume I'd want to call either its `succeeded` or its `failed` method, but the documentation is silent on the point. The documentation *does* say that the return value of `send` "resolves to" `RecordMetadata`, but I haven't been able to figure out, from either the documentation or the code, what "resolves to" means in this context.)

Anyway: I can't be the only person using kafka-python 1.3.3 who's ever tried to send messages with a partitioning key, and I have not seen anything on teh Intertubes describing a similar problem (except for the SO question I referenced at the top of this post).

I'm certainly willing to believe that I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what that might be. Is there some additional parameter I need to supply to the `KafkaProducer` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem turned out to be that my key value was a `unicode`, even though I was quite convinced that it was a `str`. Hence the selection of `str.encode` for my `key_serializer` was inappropriate, and was what led to the exception from `res.get`. Omitting the `key_serializer` and calling `key.encode('utf-8')` was enough to get my messages published, and partitioned as expected.

A large contributor to the obscurity of this problem (for me) was that the kafka-python 1.3.3 [documentation](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.3/) does not go into any detail on what a `FutureRecordMetadata` really is, nor what one should expect in the way of exceptions its `get` method can raise. The sole usage example in the documentation:

```
# Asynchronous by default
future = producer.send('my-topic', b'raw_bytes')

# Block for 'synchronous' sends
try:
    record_metadata = future.get(timeout=10)
except KafkaError:
    # Decide what to do if produce request failed...
    log.exception()
    pass
```

suggests that the only kind of exception it will raise is `KafkaError`, *which is not true*. In fact, `get` can and will (re-)raise **any** exception that the asynchronous publishing mechanism encountered in trying to get the message out the door.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same error. Once I added json.dumps while sending the key, it worked.

```
producer.send(topic="first_topic", key=json.dumps(key)
.encode('utf-8'), value=json.dumps(msg)
.encode('utf-8'))
.add_callback(on_send_success).add_errback(on_send_error)
```